# AndroidStudio(3.0) emulator not starting (Ubuntu 16.04) libGL error and more

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Since today I can't launch the emulator anymore (didn't change anything in the settings or something like that). I also tried an older version of my program, which definitely worked but it appears that some AndroidStudio files are corrupted or something like that.
Here is the event log:

> 16:45 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 16:45  Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
>
> 16:45  Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>
> 16:45  Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
>
> 16:45  Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
>
> 16:45  Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
>
> 16:45  Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0
>
> 16:45  Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  46
>
> 16:45  Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  47
>
> 16:45  Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
>
> 16:45  Gradle build finished in 840ms

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?